# Laravel how to create one object from two separated collections?

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an collection:

```
$collection1 = [ 'file1', 'file2' ];
```

I want to add properties to `collection1`

```
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];
```

to have:

```
$collection1 = [ 'file1' => [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ],
 'file2' => [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ] ];
```

how can I do it?

I tried something like:

```
 $collection1[0]->push($collection2);
 $collection1[1]->push($collection2);
```

But it's not working. I don't know why this is not working out-of-the-box like in javascript. :/

Comment: Lol, how exactly would this work out of box on Javascript?

Comment: not lol: this.collection1[1] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.collection2)) DONE

Comment: why you 2 guys are talking about .js when tags are php and laravel?

Comment: js is dirty as hell, but it gets the job done fast

Comment: Please remain on-topic.

Comment: @Devon and that's true! lol

Comment: Php and js are 2 great languages that cant be comapared ( do you use them for doing same things?). btw my answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$collection1 = [ 'file1', 'file2' ];
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];

$newCollection = collect($collection1)->flip()->map(function() use ($collection2) { 
return $collection2;
        });

dd($newCollection);
```

or this code:

```
$collection1 = collect([]);
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];


$collection1->put('file1', $collection2);
$collection1->put('file2', $collection2);

dd($collection1);
```

or this code:

```
$collection1 = [ 'file1', 'file2' ];
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];

$test = collect($collection1)->map(function ($file) use ($collection2) {
    return [$file => $collection2];
});

dd($test);
```

or this code:

```
$collection1 = [ 'file1', 'file2' ];
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];


$newCollection = collect($collection1)->flatMap(function ($file) use ($collection2) {
    return [$file => $collection2];
});

dd($newCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, try something like this:

```
$newCollection = [];
$collection1 = [ 'file1', 'file2' ];
$collection2 = [ 'property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2' ];
$newCollection["file1"] =  $collection2;
$newCollection["file2"] =  $collection2;
print_r($newCollection);
```

It output :

```
Array ( [file1] => Array ( [property1] => value1 [property2] => value2 ) [file2] => Array ( [property1] => value1 [property2] => value2 ) )
```

Comment: this is giving `"message": "Undefined index: "file1"`